# GWT, how to make i18n for @DefaultStringArrayValue messages

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I am trying to make my app run on multiple locales and I read from [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html)
How to make static texts work in different locales. But anyone knows how to do this [@DefaultStringArrayValue](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.DefaultStringArrayValue.html) one work with i18n locales.
ie if I have following:

```
@DefaultStringArrayValue({"RDY", "Ready", "HLD", "Held", "RUN", "Run", "FIN", "Finished", "MSG", "Message", "END", "End", "ERR", "Error"})
String[] jobStatuses();
```

How to create an entry in property file for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the Javadoc say it all?

> Note that in the corresponding properties/etc file, commas are used to separate elements of the array unless they are preceded with a backslash.

```
jobStatuses=RDY,Ready,HLD,Held,RUN,Run,FIN,Finished,MSG,Message,END,End,ERR,Error
```

Comment: It does actually, I misunderstood it.

Comment: @user3143318 Not to worry, happens to all of us.